# Grant insert/update access to schema

Tags: oracle, database-design, schema, database-administration, sql-grant

I have a request to grant user **TOM** Insert/Update access to all the tables on a schema **JERRY**.
I use the following query achieve it.

```
FOR x IN (SELECT * FROM user_tables)
LOOP   
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON ' || x.table_name || ' TO <<someone>>'; 
END LOOP;
```

After granting the rights on the existing tables, i have to create few more tables on *JERRY* schema. Will *TOM* have insert/update access to those newly created tables?

If **NO** do i need to execute the above statement every time i create a new table?
or is there a way to grant access to the whole schema?

Comment: Does the Tom schema contain procedures/packages that need to insert/update etc the tables in the Jerry schema?

Comment: There is no way to grant access to a whole schema. If JERRY creates a new table they will have to explicitly grant rights on it to TOM.

Comment: Yes, you have to repeat that every time a new table is created. You can however automate that with a DDL trigger if needed

Comment: Like ^^ have said, this is not possible to do at this point in time. 

This is the link to the enhancement request -> https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?_afrLoop=231044866086381&id=16899440 .

Comment: @Boneist No TOM user doesn't contain any procedure

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, i also though of doing the same

Comment: @Jaag in which case, I suggest you create a role and grant the privileges to the role. Then you can grant the role to Tom, and if Dick and Harry come along needing the same privileges, it’s just a case of assigning the role to them. You would still need to add privileges to the role when a new table is created, though.